# Python - Using socket to construct URL for external Flask server's view function

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I am developing a desktop application that must send a specified url to a Flask application hosted online, and subsequently receive data from the same Flask app. 2 applications communicating back & forth. I am able to make GET and POST requests to this Flask app, but I am unaware of how to construct specific URL's which include arguments for the Flask app to receive via `request.args.get()`

Thus far my ability hasn't been entirely erroneous. I can send a request `GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost : \r\n` which in turn receives something like `b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'`

Which is well and good, I got the encoding part down.

Beyond this I am at a loss as the Flask view function needs to acquire an argument `arg` from a specific url -
 something like *myFlaskApp.com/viewfunction?h=arg*

What would be an at least *decent* form if not a minimal / pragmatic way of practicing this kind of communication? I haven't much code to show for this one; I would like to leave any stratagem open for debate. I hope you can understand. Thank you!

P.S. +<3 if you also show me how to receive and decode the Flask server's view function return value on my app client. Assumed to be an arbitrary string.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTTP client is written in python the simplest solution would be to use a higher level HTTP library like `requests` or `urllib2`. If you want to get the path mappings against your Flask app views you could print them by introspecting the `app` object and export them to json or some other format and use them in your client.

In your sockets example just use `GET /?arg=value HTTP/1.1\nHost : \r\n`.

Comment: Sound like a good plan. Unfortunately I cannot +1 because I do not have the rep. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: It seems that I am now able to get the request to the Flask server using a lower level socket, but am still clueless as to how to receive and display its view function's return value. Do I need 2 separate sockets in the same function? One to send, the other to receive? How would Flask know which socket to send data back to. Im quite lost

Comment: Disregard that, I got it working! Thank you again. I used your URL mapping in accordance with the MySocket class as per https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sockets.html